# XML XInclude - wildcard character

Tags: xml, xinclude

I have a directory hierarchy and would want to include all XML files that fit a particular pattern using XInclude. The structure is as show below.

```
Book/
├── book.xml
└── Chapter
    └── page01.xml
    └── page02.xml
    └── page03.xml
    └── page04.xml
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way of specifying wild card characters to pick a bunch of files as opposed to picking only specified files? I tried out the code below and it appears it's not valid.

   ```
   <book name="bookname" source="/home/phiri/Book/book.xml"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
     <chapter>
       <title>Title</title>
       <comments>Comments</comments>
       <storypages>001-100</storypages>
       <xi:include href="chapter/page*.xml"/>
     </chapter>
   </book>
   ```
2. Is there any other alternate XML based solution I could use as opposed to XInclude?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488704/is-it-possible-to-use-wildcards-with-xinclude-tags

Comment: @user664424: How this relates to XSLT?

Comment: @mzjn: thank you; don't know how I missed that post.... I suppose I might have to do it programmatically then; was rather hoping I could use an XML approach.
@Zlejandro: sorry about that; it doesn't relate to XSLT in any way.